# Decoding errors in elm 0.19

Tags: json, elm, ffi

I am new to elm and I having a very hard time parsing a json from html to elm and using it.

This is what I am trying to do:

In my html doc:

```
var app = Elm.Main.init({
    node: document.getElementById("app"),
    flags: questions
});
```

then in elm:

```
main =
  Browser.element { init = init, update = update, subscriptions = subscriptions, view = view }

-- MODEL

type alias Model = 
    {
       questionsToAnswer: List QuestionToAnswer
     , currentQuestion: Int
     , initializeGame: Bool
    }

type alias QuestionToAnswer =
    {
        question: String
     ,  a: String
     ,  b: String
     ,  c: String
     ,  d: String
     ,  answer: String
    }

questionDecoder : Decoder QuestionToAnswer

questionDecoder =
    map6 QuestionToAnswer 
         (field "question" string)
         (field "A" string)
         (field "B" string)
         (field "C" string)
         (field "D" string)
         (field "answer" string)

init : Json.Decode.Value -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init questions =
  (Model (getQuestions questions) 0 True, Cmd.none)

getQuestions : Json.Decode.Value -> List QuestionToAnswer

getQuestions questions =
 case(decodeValue questionDecoder questions) of
   Ok question ->
     [question]
   _ ->
       [ QuestionToAnswer "me" "me" "me" "me" "me" "me"]
```

My json looks like this:

```
{
  "question": "In mobster lingo, if you 'sing like a canary' what are you doing?",
  "A": "impersonating Sinatra",
  "B": "talking to the cops",
  "C": "killing an enemy",
  "D": "betting on horses",
  "answer": "B"
}
```

I am outputting all the response as debug.toString in the view just to see what is happening because I also don't know how to log the error that was being produced before. The compiler says my call to getQuestions questions produces a Json.Decode.error which I find difficult to believe because I think everything looks ok to me.

The error:

> "{\"question\":\"In mobster lingo, if you 'sing like a canary' what are you doing?\",\"A\":\"impersonating Sinatra\",\"B\":\"talking to the cops\",\"C\":\"killing an enemy\",\"D\":\"betting on horses\",\"answer\":\"B\"}" Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `question`

Comment: What does the error specifically say?

Comment: If I do getQuestions `questions =
 decodeValue questionDecoder questions` I get This `decodeValue` call produces:

    Result Json.Decode.Error QuestionToAnswer

But the type annotation on `getQuestions` says it should be:

    List QuestionToAnswer this happens when I remove the case. With the case I prevent the error and return me me me...

Comment: Then what does the json decode error say if you don't ignore it in the case? You can use `Json.Decode.errorToString` to make it a string.

Comment: This is the error: Problem with the given value:

"{\"question\":\"In mobster lingo, if you 'sing like a canary' what are you doing?\",\"A\":\"impersonating Sinatra\",\"B\":\"talking to the cops\",\"C\":\"killing an enemy\",\"D\":\"betting on horses\",\"answer\":\"B\"}"

Expecting an OBJECT with a field named `question`: []

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're passing a string in as `flags`, not a JSON object. If so, you can do one of two things:

**1: Parse the JSON string on the JavaScript side, before passing it to Elm via `flags`:**

```js
var app = Elm.Main.init({
    node: document.getElementById("app"),
    flags: JSON.parse(questions)
});
```

The downside to this approach is that if an error happen during parsing it happens on the JavaScript-side and has to be handled there. If you need to deal with the error in Elm, you have to pass a more complex structure to `flags` that can represent both errors and success.

**2: Use `decodeString` instead of `decodeValue`, and change the type of `init` and `getQuestions` accordingly:**

```elm
init : String -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
init questions =
  (Model (getQuestions questions) 0 True, Cmd.none)

getQuestions : String -> List QuestionToAnswer
getQuestions questions =
 case (decodeString questionDecoder questions) of
   Ok question ->
     [question]
   _ ->
       [ QuestionToAnswer "me" "me" "me" "me" "me" "me"]
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I checked my json again and I had to wrap it in square brackets for it work. I'm not sure if I should accept your answer based on how SO works because even though it didn't directly answer the question it helped me get a better idea of what was wrong.

Comment: I can edit the answer to more accurately answer the question. Or you can add your own answer. But as it is the question itself is missing some vital information. There is nothing in the question that suggests adding square brackets would solve anything. If you add the missing information and let me know I'll adjust my answer.